# Receive Image using socket programming in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to receive an image in python to use it in my program.

Here is the sever code:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5005))
server_socket.listen(5)

data = ' ' 
client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
print "Conencted to - ",address,"\n"
while (1):
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print "The following data was received - ",data
    print "Opening file - ",data
    img = open(data,'r')
    while True:
      strng = img.readline(512)
      if not strng:
        break
      client_socket.send(strng)
      img.close()
      print "Data sent successfully"
      exit()
      #data = 'viewnior '+data
      #os.system(data)
```

And here is the client code:

```
import socket,os
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5005))
size = 1024

while(1):
    print "Enter file name of the image with extentsion (example: filename.jpg,filename.png or if a video file then filename.mpg etc) - "
    fname = raw_input()
    client_socket.send(fname)
    #fname = 'documents/'+fname
    fp = open(fname,'w')
    while True:
        strng = client_socket.recv(512)
        if not strng:
            break
        fp.write(strng)
    fp.close()
    print "Data Received successfully"
    exit()
    #data = 'viewnior '+fname
    #os.system(data)
```

The received should now be read to be able to use it. I am opening it like this:

```
input_image = Image.open('data').convert('L').resize((100, 100))
```

but when I run both codes in cmd the output is:
`The following data was received - + path` `Opening file - + path`
Then nothing happens although the image should be used and the final output should be shown.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I assume you are using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)? Anyway, is the received JPEG valid, or has it been corrupted during the transfer? Are you able to open it with an other program?

Comment: Yes I am using PIL. How can I know if it has been corrupted during transfer or not?

Comment: Please read more carefully my previous comment: "Are you able to open [your received file] with an other program?" Gimp, Photoshop or whatever will tell you if it is still a valid JPEG or not. You might still want to compare the size of both the original and received file. But maybe your problem is not here? I'm just _guessing_ -- or at least naming the first few things that I would have checked if I were you...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your (only) problem, but when working with binary files, you should pass the `b` flag to the built-in function [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

```
img = open(data, 'rb')
```

Comment: This was indeed *not* the only problem. By looking more closely to your code, and given the output you observed, I assume the variable data (which should contain the file name) is empty. Are you sure sockets.recv is working as you expect in `data = client_socket.recv(1024)`?