# Sending screen capture from a C# Unity project to a Python socket

Tags: c#, python, sockets, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a project in which I have a virtual environment with cameras and want to send screenshots of selected cameras through a socket to a python client that will be running on a raspberry pi zero. In the raspberry I will have additional processing but that is not my current issue.

I've looked into screencapturing in unity, there was a project that appeared to do the capturing part quite right although I'm having some trouble adapting the code from https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/screenshot-helper-102472 
I have

```
 ScreenshortHelper.iCaptureWithCamera(camera, (texture2D) => {//Code}};
```

Would I be able to insert the "send" code in the "//Code" block?

Also that part for me is a bit tricky, sending the "texture" through the socket, I was thinking about sending some parameters like size and dimensions first so that I know what I would be receiving on the python end. Does this make sense?

I appreciate any help that you can give me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to configure the [Transport Layer API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html) in your unity code, and put references to your `hostId` and your `channelId` somewhere where that function can access it.

Then,  that anonymous function there can be:

```
(texture2D) => {
    // Encode it to PNG bytes and put it into a buffer:
    byte[] buffer = texture2D.EncodeToPNG();

    // Connect to the python listener:
    byte error;
    connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, "192.168.1.42", 8888, 0, out error);

    // Send:
    int bufferLength = bytes.Length;
    NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, connectionId, channelId, buffer, bufferLength, out error);

    // Disconnect:
    NetworkTransport.Disconnect(hostId, connectionId, out error);
}
```

And then on the other side, you can use Python to listen on a binary stream, and then do whatever you need to do with it. There is some useful information on how to read an image over a socket in python here: [Receive Image using socket programming in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990104/receive-image-using-socket-programming-in-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it!